# I'm trying to use Logstash's twitter input, which utilizes this library to connect to the streaming API. I am getting Unauthorized error

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use Logstash's twitter input, which utilizes this library to connect to the streaming API. I am getting Unauthorized error:

Exception: Twitter::Error::Unauthorized
  Stack: /root/logstash-master/vendor/...
Elasticsearch_1.7.1
Logsh-1.5.3
Java 1.7.0_79

Comment: If somebody editing your code to be more readable do not revert it

Comment: would u mind to share your configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

While copying the `consumer` or other keys into the log-stash configuration, don't give space (by-mistake it happens while pasting)
For example:

```
consumer_key => "qzjGZhDxg5vvVTlPpZQnKOnRB"  //this is correct

consumer_key => " qzjGZhDxg5vvVTlPpZQnKOnRB"  //this is wrong because space is also a character
```

This is also one of the cause for getting this exception.